# Installing a CMS Engine with Ruby on Rails. (Locomotive)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, locomotivecms

Locomotive as an open source CMS for ruby on rails, which I'd like to install.

I've got on well with their 'getting started' projects, but I'm having trouble installing the Locomotive CMS Engine.

Here's a link to the requirements:

http://doc.locomotivecms.com/guides/get-started/requirements

...and here's a link to the actual guide that installs the CMS Engine:

http://doc.locomotivecms.com/guides/get-started/install-engine

Okay, so first, Ruby needs to be installed, version 1.9.3 at least:
[image: terminal screen shot, demonstrating what version of ruby is installed]

Next, imagemagick needs to be installed. Imagemagick is an open source software suite for displaying, converting, and editing raster image files. When installed, it warns me that I have either mac ports or fink installed, even though I've removed both. **I have no idea what to do about those malformed objects!**

[image: terminal screenshot showing imagemagick installation errors]

Anyway, let's push on. Now we need to install rails version 3.2.11:
[image: terminal screenshot showing loaded version of rails]

Great. Now we need to install MongoDB, an open-source document database, and the leading NoSQL database.

[image: terminal screenshot showing MongoDB output]
A few things are wrong here.
Launchctl didn't return anything? Why not? Running 'Mongod' resulted in no out put whatsoever either. Bad signs.

Now, rake and bundler need to be installed. No problems:

[image: terminal screenshot verifying bundler is installed]
[image: terminal screenshot verifying rake is installed]

Next the wagon gem needs to be installed. Wagon is a command line site generator for the LocomotiveCMS engine. Installs without complaint:

[image: terminal screenshot verifying wagon is installed]

Finally it's time for the application to be generated! I've called it 'myapp' and created it using the following command:

```
rails new myapp --skip-active-record --skip-test-unit --skip-javascript --skip-bundle
```

Now I enter the root directory of 'myapp' with:

```
cd myapp
```

Include the relevant gems in the Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
gem 'locomotive_cms', '~> 2.0.1', :require => 'locomotive/engine'
gem 'unicorn', :group => 'development'
gem 'compass-rails',  '~> 1.0.2', :group => 'assets'
gem 'sass-rails',     '~> 3.2.4', :group => 'assets'
gem 'coffee-rails',   '~> 3.2.2', :group => 'assets'
gem 'uglifier',       '~> 1.2.4', :group => 'assets'
end
```

Run 'bundle install'. No problems at all:
[image]

**But here, here is where I think is where the errors come into play. It has everything to do with Mongoid.**

The following command is used to insert the engine routes to the main application:

```
bundle exec rails g locomotive:install
```

and it results in the following warnings:

```
  create  config/initializers/locomotive.rb
  create  config/initializers/carrierwave.rb
  create  config/initializers/dragonfly.rb
  create  config/mongoid.yml
    rake  db:mongoid:migration:install/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-     p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197: warning: Insecure world writable    dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
rake aborted!
Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:413:in      `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:574:in     `setup'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:104:in     `initialize'
```

and

```
rake  db:mongoid:migrate
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:197:     warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local in PATH, mode 040777
rake aborted!
Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:413:in  `connect'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:574:in   `setup'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/mongo-1.5.2/lib/mongo/connection.rb:104:in   `initialize'
```

The instructions say to also "configure your mongodb hostname and database name in config/mongoid.yml." I've left them as:

```
defaults: &defaults
host: localhost
port: 27017
# slaves:
#   - host: slave1.local
#     port: 27018
#   - host: slave2.local
#     port: 27019

development:
<<: *defaults
database: locomotive_dev

test:
<<: *defaults
database: locomotive_test
```

The instructions also say to set "multisite activation, default locale, email sender (etc) in config/initializers/locomotive.rb." Again, I've simply left it as:

```
Locomotive.configure do |config|
 config.multi_sites = false
 config.default_locale = :en
 config.enable_logs = true
 config.mailer_sender = 'support@example.com'
end
```

Moment of truth now. Starting the server with:

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails
```

Spent a good six hours on this. All I get is

```
E, [2013-04-29T20:41:49.223219 #40521] ERROR -- : reaped #<Process::Status: pid 40527 exit 1>     worker=0
I, [2013-04-29T20:41:49.223661 #40521]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawning...
I, [2013-04-29T20:41:49.225155 #40528]  INFO -- : worker=0 spawned pid=40528
I, [2013-04-29T20:41:49.225574 #40528]  INFO -- : Refreshing Gem list
E, [2013-04-29T20:41:52.211379 #40528] ERROR -- : Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
```

In a word: awergohiewgiohegwhioewgiohwefiohfwaehioiohawefiohawefhioaewfohiafwehioafwiohaiofwehiofaewiohaefwihoefwahioaefwhioaefwhoiiohaefwhioefwhioaefwhioaefwhioaefwiohafewiohaefwohifaewiohaefwhioafewhiofaewhiofewaiohefwaohieawfiohfewhiofewhiofeawhiofaewhoieafwhioawefhioawfeiohawfeohi.

If someone could help out with, I would be so, so, so thankful. I think this is the key:

```
Failed to connect to a master node at localhost:27017 (Mongo::ConnectionFailure)
```

Comment: Hey @Starkers  how is locomotive.  I just started messing with it and so far so good. Any  suggestions on the local engine deployment.  Cuz I am getting an error.  Like an article you recommend of something .  Thanks for this post anyways. Very helpful  ++

Comment: Thanks, but I can't really answer you. My own simple CMS is all I need for most clients so I don't use Locomotive. This is what I use if my own simple cms won't cut it: http://alchemy-cms.com/about I'm not knocking Locomotive though, I think the BBC iplayer uses it so I think it's up to most tasks.

Comment: you can also check out this one   http://nestacms.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to start the mongo database engine.

**Just before running:**

```
bundle exec unicorn_rails
```

run

```
sudo mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb.log
```

starting the unicorn rails server will now result in no errors.

Optional, run

```
tail -f /var/log/mongodb.log
```

To see a live log as your application interacts with the database!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the devise initializer file and ran the 
`rails g devise:install`
 again and then started the unicorn server and everything was working fine.